# Truncate hive-1.0 timestamp to seconds and change format from "yyyy:mm:dd:ss.SSS" to "yyyy:mm:dd:ss"

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, milliseconds

Basically the title:

I am looking for a reasonable way, with only hive-1.0 syntax, to truncate only the milliseconds field off a timestamp.

The hyper naive approach I am considering is:

```
cast(from_unixtime(second(cast([TIMESTAMP_IN_QUESTION] as string)), "yyyy:mm:dd:ss"), as timestamp)
```

But I believe this include the .00 on the milliseconds field at the end.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firt of all, correct timestamp format is

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

By default timestamp without milliseconds will be printed with `.00` or `.0` at the end. Because it is string representation of timestamp. If you want it to be without milliseconds part, convert it to string and specify format explicitly or just use substring to get value without milliseconds. substr() will work correctly with timestamps as well as string literals also. This is the simplest way if you only want to remove milliseconds without changing everything else:

```
select substr('2020-01-01 12:10:10.123',1,19)
```

Returns:

```
2020-01-01 12:10:10
```