# There are multiple '. 0' after sqoop exports data from Mysql to hive datetime type

Tags: hive, timestamp, sqoop

### mysql type is datetime,hive is string or timestamp
there are all happen in hive table

mysql

2016-10-13 15:18:10

2016-10-13 15:18:10

2016-10-13 15:18:10

2016-10-13 15:18:10

2016-10-13 15:18:10

2016-10-13 15:18:10

---

hive

2016-10-13 15:18:10.0

2016-10-13 15:18:10.0

2016-10-13 15:18:10.0

2016-10-13 15:18:10.0

2016-10-13 15:18:10.0

2016-10-13 15:18:10.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive default timestamp string representation format is `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'` and this is why it is being converted to string in this format implicitly, the same happens when the Hive datatype is timestamp and you selecting it, if you have no milliseconds, it is displayed with `.0`. If you want to suppress `.0`, store value as STRING in Hive and do explicit conversion to string in the query using [date_format function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63937814/2700344